# How to parse the dataframe column into column

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a dataframe with two column having json data I want to parse that json data into the column my dataframe is

```
+------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|   firstname| lastname|    travellerdetails|            bookjson|
+------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|           K|    Gupta|[{FlierNumber:","...|[{origin:DEL","Et...|
|           K|    Gupta|[{FlierNumber:","...|[{origin:DEL","Et...|
|Jana Ranjani|Raghu Raj|[{BaggageTypeRetu...|[{origin:AMD","De...|
+------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

There are two column having json data and I want to parse that column

`The first row of travellerdetails is` :

```
""[{""""FlierNumber"""":""""""""","BaggageTypeReturn"""":""""""""","FirstName"""":""""K""""","Title"""":""""1""""","MiddleName"""":""""D""""","LastName"""":""""Gupta""""","MealTypeOnward"""":""""""""","DateOfBirth"""":""""""""","BaggageTypeOnward"""":""""""""","SeatTypeOnward"""":""""""""","MealTypeReturn"""":""""""""","FrequentAirline"""":null","Type"""":""""A""""","SeatTypeReturn"""":""""""""}","{""""FlierNumber"""":""""""""","BaggageTypeReturn"""":""""""""","FirstName"""":""""Sweety""""","Title"""":""""2""""","MiddleName"""":""""""""","LastName"""":""""Gupta""""","MealTypeOnward"""":""""""""","DateOfBirth"""":""""""""","BaggageTypeOnward"""":""""""""","SeatTypeOnward"""":""""""""","MealTypeReturn"""":""""""""","FrequentAirline"""":null","Type"""":""""A""""","SeatTypeReturn"""":""""""""}]""
```

`the first row of bookjson is`:

```
""[{""""origin"""":""""DEL""""","EticketFlag"""":""""false""""","flightcode"""":""""251""""","farebasis"""":""""L0IP""""","spicestatus"""":""""Canceled""""","deptime"""":""""07:20""""","codeshare"""":""""""""","ibibopartner"""":""""indigonew""""","productclass"""":""""R""""","duration"""":""""2h 5m""""","ruleno"""":""""4910""""","qtype"""":""""fbs""""","tickettype"""":""""e""""","flightno"""":""""251""""","servicetype"""":""""""""","fareclass"""":""""L""""","faresequence"""":""""1""""","destination"""":""""GAU""""","carrierid"""":""""6E""""","stops"""":""""0""""","state"""":""""New""""","fare"""":{""""adultphf"""":50","adultttf"""":75","adultdf"""":115","totalsurcharge"""":0","indigonewgrossamount"""":10202","adulttotalfare"""":5101","totalcommission"""":0","adultbasefare"""":4150","totalpassengerhandlingfee"""":0","adultudf"""":562","adultpassengerservicefee"""":149","totalpassengerservicefee"""":0","totalothers"""":0","childtotalfare"""":0","totalbasefare"""":8300","totalfare"""":101...
```

please help me how to parse the column..??

Comment: The samples you posted are incorrect  `json` formats

Comment: I have that data and I want to convert it I read about it so I found there is a function in python ```get_json_object()``` so I is possible to parse that column

Comment: I have update the original data please check

Comment: Good question! Keep up @CoolTriks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`F.from_json()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json).

You would use it like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("travellerdetails", F.from_json(F.col("travellerdetails")))
df = df.withColumn("bookjson", F.from_json(F.col("bookjson")))
```

However, please note that the JSON you have give in your question is invalid, so it would result in `null`.
Also note that you can pass a schema to `from_json` as the second argument - this might speed up the parsing and allows you to specify the data type you want for each field.

Comment: I have update the original data please check I just remove the quotes please help me how can I do it....??

Comment: The data still does not look like a valid JSON string. But have you tried the solution from my answer? If you have valid JSON, it should work like that.